# The Wowza Streaming Engine Manager IP address was blocked by the Wowza Streaming Engine server.

Tags: wowza

The Wowza Streaming Engine Manager IP address was blocked by the Wowza Streaming Engine server.

When I tried to open my WSEM, I got this problem.

But it works perfect last week.

[The Picture Of My Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/agRBC.png)

Answer (score 3):

Restart the Wowza services first. if this does not work do the following:
open conf/server.xml and edit the  element. Check that 127.0.0.1 is set there, if it is there add the local IP (separate the IP with comma), restart and try to access the engine manager via that local IP.

Comment: thanks very much, I re-install my Wowza Yesterday, and it works again!